# Why CPU usage not increase?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, concurrency, cpu

Having the second code:

```
class Methods
{
    public MemoryStream UniqPicture(string imagePath)
    {
        var photoBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath); // change imagePath with a valid image path
        var quality = 70;
        var format = ImageFormat.Jpeg; // we gonna convert a jpeg image to a png one
        var size = new Size(200, 200);

        using (var inStream = new MemoryStream(photoBytes))
        {
            using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                using (var imageFactory = new ImageFactory())
                {

                    imageFactory.Load(inStream)
                        .Rotate(new Random().Next(-7, 7))
                        .RoundedCorners(new RoundedCornerLayer(190))
                        .Pixelate(3, null)
                        .Contrast(new Random().Next(-15, 15))
                        .Brightness(new Random().Next(-15, 15))
                        .Quality(quality)
                        .Save(outStream);
                }

                return outStream;
            }
        }
    }

    public void StartUniq()
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles("mypath");
        Parallel.ForEach(files, (picture) => { UniqPicture(picture); });
    }

}
```

When I start method StartUniq() my CPU bound to 12-13% and no more. Can I use more CPU % for doing this operation? Why it not increase?

I try to do it from python, it's also only 12-13%. It's Core i7 8700.

The only way to do it operation faster it's to start the second window of application.

It's windows limit? Using Windows Server 2016.

I think this is system limit, because if I try this simple code it's bound 12% CPU too!

```
 while (true)
        {
            var a = 1 + 2;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you think that using more CPU will cause it to go quicker? Your CPU has 6 cores, and looks like 100/6 => 16 so it's perhaps using all of one core (it's not optimized for multi-core processing). Process more files in parallel if you can't modify it to make it multi-threaded. If you only have one file to process, you're probaly out of luck

Comment: My guess would be that either you are disk IO bound, or possibly the library you are using from your ImageFactory is written so that it is single threaded.

Comment: I'd measure the File I/O against the Image Processing. One of them is probably faster than the other. Only with these results I'd consider how to optimize.

Comment: I have to try start it creating new Task, new Thread. Also trying to create tasks for every image, no one way helps.

Comment: Have you try to increase the [Priority Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.priority) of the Thread.CurrentThread to Highest, or `Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime` (dangerous) ?

Comment: No, but I test it in application which have no one another threads, so it must work without Priority.

Comment: If you look into resource manager's CPU tab, you can see your cores. I guess there will be one of them pretty busy, the others not. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, I have already look at the cores, they works evenly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of research shows that you are using ImageFactory from https://imageprocessor.org/, which wraps System.Drawing.  System.Drawing itself is often a wrapper for GDI/GDI+, which... incorporates process-wide locks, so your attempts at multithreading will be severely bottlenecked.  Try a better image library.

Comment: If performance is really important for your project, then you might want to consider investigating using https://imageresizing.net/ which I have used in various projects in the past and worked very well performance wise.  Quality is ok, some more advanced features aren't free, and filesize (compression) isn't great.  But it's rock solid and superfast.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try some another library.

Answer (score 1):

(See Robert McKee's answer, although maybe this could be about disk IO but maybe not.)

So, I haven't used `Paralell.ForEach` before, but it seems like you should be running your `UniqPicture` method in parallel for all files in a given directory. I think your approach is good here, but ultimately your hard drive is probably killing the speed of your program (and vice versa).

Have you tried running `UniqPicture` in a loop sequentially? My concern here is that your hard drive is thrashing possibly. But in general, it's most likely that the input / output (IO) from your hard drive is taking a considerable amount of time, so the CPU is waiting a considerable amount of time before it can operate on the images in `UniqPicture`. If you could pre-load the images into memory, I would think the CPU utilization would be much higher, if not maxing out your CPU.

In no particular order, here are some thoughts

1. What happens if you run this sequentially? This will max out one core on the CPU at max, but it may prevent hard drive thrashing. If there are 100 threads being spun up, that's a lot of requests for the hard drive to deal with at once.

You should be able to add this option to make it run sequentially (or just make it a normal loop without `Parallel.`):

`new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 },`

Maybe try 2, 3, or 4 threads and see if anything changes.

1. Check your hard drive utilization in task manager. What's the latency on the hard drive where the images are stored? What's the percentage that Winows reports it as busy? You want the hard drive to be busy the entire time (100% usage), but you also want it to be grabbing your images with the highest throughput possible so the CPU can do its job.
2. A spinning hard drive (HDD) has far lower IOPS (IO per second) than an SSD in general. An SSD will usually have 1000 to 100,000+ IOPS, but a HDD is around 200, I believe, and has much lower throughput usually. An SSD should help your program utilize the CPU much more.
3. The size of the image files could have an impact here, again relating to IO.
4. Or maybe see [Robert Mckee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/856353/robert-mckee)'s answer about your threads getting bottlenecked. Maybe 13% CPU utilization is the best you can get. 1 / 6 (your CPU has 6 cores) cores being maxed is ~16.7%, so you actually aren't that far off on maxing one core already.
5. Ultimately, time how long it's taking. CPU utilization *should* scale inversely  linearly (higher CPU usage = lower run time) with the time this takes to run, but time it just be to be sure since that's the real benchmark.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, MaxDegreeOfParallelism not changes everything. Not sure that it can be my SSD - when I start my app in second window it works in the same speed. Not really understand why my first window can't working like two windows of app

Comment: @Keln Are you saying your CPU usage doubles if you run two instances (two _processes_) of this program at once? That makes sense based on the other comments because maybe you are limited to one thread due to the library you are using. You aren't going to get better than ~16.7% usage (1 / 6 cores) per process, where a process is another "window" of your program.

Even though you have an SSD, IO (reading the bytes for the images) is still an important factor to consider, although (again) maybe it's the library you're using that's the biggest bottleneck.